# How to implement Search functionality without Adapter for Treeview in Android

Tags: android

I want to make `Search` functionality in **Treeview**, now the problem is that in my **treeview** adapter is not used and without adapter `Search` is not possible so now how I can do search in Treeview.
  [I have used Treeview concept from this link.](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView)

Please Give me Solution.
Thank you.